# Microsoft Azure Login not work as expected in electron application

Tags: electron, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication, electron-packager

This Application is Develop in React.js and then we are using electron to create desktop application,
we have implemented the Microsoft Azure (MFA) Login authentication.

Login and process is working fine in react application, but in electron application when i try to login it's not showing all the login credentials that is already login on the system.
and asking for password and when i open the i-frame with in the application ,it again asking for credentials and i don't want to appear the credentials screen multiple time with in the application.

The reason i behind this i am understanding is that, react has the access of all the extension of the chrome on system, but electron don't have the access the all the extension that is used by system browser.

is there any way by using that i can access the same chrome extensions in our electron application?
is there any way by follow that we can show all the credentials of MFA that is login in our system to our electron application and ask user to fill their credentials again and again?

is there any way by using that i can access the same chrome extensions in our electron application?
is there any way by follow that we can show all the credentials of MFA that is login in our system to our electron application and ask user to fill their credentials again and again?